# QVBoxLayout - setting alignment

Tags: qt

I have QGroupBox which using QVBoxLayout:

```
 QVBoxLayout *vbLayout1 = new QVBoxLayout(groupBox1);
 vbLayout1->addWidget(label1);
 vbLayout1->addWidget(slider1);
 groupBox1->setLayout(vbLayout1);
```

A height of the group box is big enough to store more than two elements so when I add to the layout only two elements as above, the first appears in the middle of the group box and the second in the bottom. I want to set an alignment where elements are placed in the group box from top to bottom with some small spacing. How to achieve such alignment ? How set spacing between elements ?

Comment: Did you try to call `vbLayout1->addStretch();` after adding the slider to layout?

Comment: Thanks, works fine, but if you have more group boxes which are also in the vertical layout it will has an influence on it. Then you have to create for them QSizePolicy and set a vertical strech.I also call addSpacing between addWidget to set spacing. I wonder how to work following methods: setStretch, setSpacing and setAlignment ?  Could you explain that in practice ?

Comment: You can add stretch also in the bottom of the vertical layout that holds your group boxes.